# GAE + Spring MVC : Saving image file to BlobStore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, blobstore

i succesfully save an image to Blob in Datastore with this code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(ModelMap model, Product form, HttpServletRequest request) {
      if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) { // if(form.getImage().getBytes().getSize() != 0) {
          try { 
              Blob file = new Blob(form.getImage().getBytes()); 
              form.setImg(file);
          } catch (IOException  e) { 
              e.printStackTrace(); 
          }
      }
 //save to datastore etc
}
```

And i just try to save it in BlobStore and just save the Blob key in datastore. is it posible? this is my snippet but no works :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(ModelMap model, Product form, HttpServletRequest request) {
      Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(request);
      BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("image");
      form.setImage1(blobKey); 
      //save to datastore etc
}
```

i learn from [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob) example. and i got this error :

```
Must be called from a blob upload callback request.
```

Stack Trace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from a blob upload callback request.
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.getUploads(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:160)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.getUploadedBlobs(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:144)
at com.shop.controller.ProductController.add(ProductController.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    ....
```

**Solution :**

Finally i found it that i need to generate url in my jsp :

```
<form:form action='<%=blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/admin/product/add")%>' commandName="product" methodParam="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of saving blobkey, try saving its string representation via

```
 String blobStr = blobKey.getKeyString();
```

String representations can be easily serialized and saved in DataStore. You can always construct back BlobKey instance from their String representation

```
 BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(blobStr);
```

Comment: thanks for your sugestion but this error occur when run this line `Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(request);`

Comment: apologies, looks like you are running into a known [bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3223) . there is a work around mentioned in the last comment.
 Just to reconfirm, you may try the sample code as it is in a fresh project.